# How many organs can be harvest without killing prisoners?

Tags: rimworld

In RimWorld harvesting some organs will kill the prisoners immediately.  I would like to know how many organs can be harvested so that we can get maximum use out of them (prisoners).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Organ harvesting is a profitable venture, but it comes with some major costs. For starters, your relationship with the faction the prisoner belongs to will decrease by 20 points. If it's someone from your own colony, that person will have a -30 mood penalty, and other colonists will get a -5 penalty.

According to the [wiki](https://rimworldwiki.com/wiki/Body_Parts), you can harvest one kidney and one lung from a prisoner without actually killing them. If you harvest any of the other organs (heart or liver), or if you harvest the second kidney or lung, the prisoner will die.

Organ harvesting is definitely a lucrative business, but due to the mood penalties it's usually more efficient to focus on a different money making method. Only harvest organs if your colonists can afford multiple mood debuffs for a long period of time.

Comment: You could add that certain colonist traits (i.e. psychopath, cannibal, bloodthirsty) make your colonists more tolerant of killing and removing organs from prisoners.